# The best way to swapping connectionString parameters on runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class generated by EF.

```
public partial class AMIEntities : DbContext
{
    public AMIEntities()
        : base("name=AMIEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<AMI_DATA> AMI_DATA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AMI_DATA_HISTORY> AMI_DATA_HISTORY { get; set; }
}
```

In the app.config file in the connectionString I store the encrypted password to MSSQL server. Where can I add code to replace the connectionString for all calls in your application without changes already created the code?

```
using (var context = new AMIEntities())
{
  var test = context.TABLE.ToList();
}
```

What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I absolutely hate working on generated code you can add the following constructor to your `AMIEntities` class.

```
public AMIEntities(string connectionString)
  :base(connectionString)
{ }
```

you can then swap out your connection string in runtime to access another database, e.g.

```
using (var context = new AMIEntities(your_New_ConnectionString))
{
  var test = context.TABLE.ToList();
}
```

**Note:** you are going to have to pass through either an EF connection string or you have to build a new EF connection from a simple connection string.

### UPDATE

For the purposes of retaining your code change even when the generated code is re-generated, you can create a class that inherits from your `AMIEntities` class and set your constructor there, basically:

```
public class AMIEntitiesExtended : AMIEntities
{
    public AMIEntitiesExtended (string connectionString)
      :base(connectionString)
    { } 

}
```

and then call your new class instead of the generated class:

```
using (var context = new AMIEntitiesExtended(your_New_ConnectionString))
{
  var test = context.TABLE.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Editing generated code is never a good idea, who knows if/when any change will be overwritten and disappear ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did it in this way, also have not found anything more meaningful.